# Python TypeError in my-code,

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7

I am getting this error while running the program below. I am running this code on CentOS. I don't know what is the problem is!

I'm stuck with this error: `TypeError: put_photo() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)`

```
#!/usr/bin/python:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sys import argv
#import tweepy
import facebook

def main():
  cfg = {
    "page_id"      : "XXXX",
    "access_token" : "XXXX"
    }
  api = get_api(cfg)
  msg = "Hello, world!"
  status = api.put_wall_post(msg)

def get_api(cfg):
  graph = facebook.graphapi(cfg['access_token'])
  resp = graph.get_object('me/accounts')
  page_access_token = None
  for page in resp['data']:
    if page['id'] == cfg['page_id']:
      page_access_token = page['access_token']
  graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
  '''
  caption = "இன்ரைய நாள் காட்டி  #tamilcalender (©belongs to watermarked party)"
  albumid = ''
  with open(image.jpg,"rb") as image:
          posted_image_id = graph.put_photo(image, caption, albumid) '''
  return graph
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: `graph.put_photo(image, caption, albumid)` has 4 arguments. It doesn't look like it, but that's because the first one is hidden, (`self`). You are passing 1 too many things into the method.

Comment: You're passing four arguments in that call to `put_photo`. The object the method is attached to (`graph`) is automatically passed in as the first argument, traditionally called `self`. Then you pass in three more yourself for a total of four. Look at the documentation or the `help()` for that method to figure out how to call it.

Answer (score 1):

`put_photo` API takes only two arguments.

- `image` - A file object representing the image to be uploaded.
- `album_path` - A path representing where the image should be uploaded. Defaults to /me/photos which creates/uses a custom album for each Facebook application.

[Please check this link for more info.](http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=put_photo)

You are passing three aruguments - `image, caption, albumid`.

Along with these three, as explained in above comments by **@kindall** and **@BrandonIbbotson**, the one mandatory argument is passed which is related to `self`.

Just check above link for examples and just pass two valid arguments.